# How do I set a password on an Ubuntu cloud image?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-vsphere, virtualbox

I'm trying to start on .ova with VirtualBox and want to import the same image later in vSphere.

Ubuntu cloud images don't have a standard password anymore.

I'd like to edit the .ova to configure a password. (and later SSH keys)

The downloaded .ova does have a password property.

I found a tool called `cot` (Common OVF tool) to edit the properties.

I tried:

```
cot edit-properties ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-custom.ova -p password=ubuntu
```

Also also tried:

```
cot edit-properties ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-custom.ova -p user-data="password: ubuntu"
```

Both attempts without success. (unable to login)

Is there a step to apply this configuration into the images, or do these properties get passed to the image when it starts?

Any ideas?

**Updated:** (answers to background questions)

1. As a first step I want root access, so I can test the network setup of adapter, bridge, routes, DNS.
2. A new user with ssh key and sudo is 2nd goal.
3. Ubuntu 17.10 (soon 18.04)
4. VirtualBox 5.2.14
5. vSphere 5.5

Comment: You can use ubuntu recovery mode, to change root password. Described here: [https://shruthigurudath.medium.com/reset-password-using-an-ubuntu-root-shell-7056c59a23ea](https://shruthigurudath.medium.com/reset-password-using-an-ubuntu-root-shell-7056c59a23ea)
Later, when you have access to the system, you can add other users and disable root login if you want..

Comment: The default username is `ubuntu` and you can set the password during deployment in the OVA options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Questions

It would be useful if you could add background information to the question, like:

1. Why do you need to set a root password. Maybe there is an alternative way. What are you trying to accomplish?
2. According to (1), the recommended way might be one among several options: root user with password, a new user with ssh key and sudo, others.)
3. What's your host operating system?
4. VirtualBox version?
5. VMWare vsphere version?

### General plan

1. Set the correct settings for Virtualbox
2. Create the user-data and meta-data files
3. Generate the ISO image for cloud-init
4. Boot the VM with the attached ISO image as a removable device

### Virtualbox

1. You can import the OVA as an appliance, use an IMG or VMDK disk. You can do this in the GUI or the command line.
2. You should enable the **serial port** in the hardware settings for the VM. *Optionally*, point it to a *raw file* in your home, so you can see the log in case of problems.
3. You need the iso/img generated below for cloud-init and mount it in the dvd or cd device for the VM you imported. If the VM doesn't include a dvd/cd device, you have to add one. Add it as IDE and master, then load the ISO generated below.

### Cloud-Init

If you are using the [Ubuntu Cloud Images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/), you should use [Cloud-Init](https://cloud-init.io/) for setting the initial configuration, it allows you to set up:

- Default locale
- Hostname
- Generating and setting up SSH private keys

... among other features.

Cloud-init's behavior can be configured via the user-data flag for inline commands or calling a YAML type config file with the settings to apply.

This is might be done via the `--user-data` or `--user-data-file` argument when you are running inline, or you can do it with the ISO. I'm going to show the steps for the ISO mount mode.

I will not setup a password for root or the user, I'm creating instead a new user with SSH access via ssh public keys and allowing the user sudo permissions instead.

Here is a sample **user-data** cloud-config file, create it with your text editor, and respect the name or the seed file won't be a valid seed and won't work.

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: eddypronk
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - <your user public key here>
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```

You can also have a meta-data for the hostname and other definitions:

```
instance-id: set-an-unique-instance-name-id
local-hostname: set-the-hostname
```

After creating the files generate an iso file to load as a cdrom or dvd from the virtual manager:

```
genisoimage -output nocloud.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

You need `genisoimage` for this or the `cloud-utils` tool `cloud-localds` for this other option:

```
cloud-localds my-seed.img my-user-data my-meta-data
```

Remember that if you leave the seed / nocloud iso mounted, it will ovewrite the settings in the VM with those in the data files. And if you change anything in user-data or meta-data you need to rebuild the iso or img.

### Boot

You can now boot the VM. By default, you can not ssh to the machine using the username and password or connect through the VNC console (the "graphical" VM window in Virtualbox). You have to use public / private key authentication method with ssh. This means enabling a user with a public ssh key in the *user-data* YAML file. Also, sudo privileges elevation for the ubuntu account is passwordless, but the account is locked by default.

Comment: Please note that the main reason for using "ssh-authorized-keys" instead of "password" is that it is much more secure. Since OP says that they will later add SSH keys, there seems to be no reason to do the complicated and less secure way first.

Comment: @Leo I generated the `nocloud.iso` and could login to the VirtualBox VM with my ssh key. No need for a password. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I followed the steps, but when I try to ssh into VM(virtualbox) I get Permission denied(public key), I have checked the permissions of keys on my host, any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

**18.04 setup step-by-step**

In short you need:

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-image-utils

cat >user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
password: asdfqwer
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF

cloud-localds user-data.img user-data

# user-data.img MUST come after the rootfs. 
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-drive file=ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img,format=qcow2 \
-drive file=user-data.img,format=raw
...
```

and now you can login with:

- username: `ubuntu`
- password: `asdfqwer`

Here I describe a full minimal detailed working QEMU example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to the possible solution https://techglimpse.com/nova-boot-instance-with-password/

Create a file called *userdata.txt* with the below contents:

```
#cloud-config
password: mypasswd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

Now, pass *userdata.txt* file as an input while creating a new instance as shown below:

```
#openstack server create --flavor m1.small --image Ubuntu-Trusty --key-name  mykey --nic net-id=88536e89-12a9-41eb-8aed-57983ee299e8 --security-group default --user-data=userdata.txt my-ubuntu
```

The above command will set password *mypasswd* for the default user *ubuntu*.

Answer (score 1):

according to their web, the password for the images are ramdomly generated.

The username will be ubuntu, but the images will 'spit out' the random generated password on their first boot.

*"Get the password for 'ubuntu' and log in The default selection in the grub menu will result in a randomly generated password for the 'ubuntu' user on first boot. The password is written two places, the console and the serial device. On the console, you will see lines like:"*

Read this link, step 4:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images

Comment: When the property 'password' is set to 'RANDOM' it should do that, but recent images have the value ''. I connected the output of the serial device to a file in VirtualBox and it doesn't 'spit out' the password. I don't see the grub menu and I doubt it has grub installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is, the password property you are setting gets reset when the VM is starting, because the cloud-init disables the password-authentication by default. 
May be you can try mounting the image and configure the cloud.cfg as below:

```
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg

#cloud-config
password: mysecret
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

This is supposed to activate password authentication and set a password, as mentioned in the following link:

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/5531/defining-default-user-password-for-ubuntu-cloud-image/

Answer (score 1):

The image you have has cloud-init installed. This means you can use
[NoCloud datasource](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html) to load the configuration from a floppy(vfat) or cd(ISO9660) image.
In that image you can have a cloud-config file where you can configure the [ssh keys](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#configure-instances-ssh-keys)

For more details read also: http://blog.klocwork.com/open-source/using-cloud-init-outside-of-the-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

There is no default username/password for the ubuntu cloud image. Need to configure it using below cmd, before creating instance from the image.

```
virt-customize -a bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img --root-password password:<pass>
```

Need to install below pkg to get `virt-customize` cmd.

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you import the OVA, boot the VM in VBox, add a password, export the VM to an OVA and use that next time you need to create a new VM?

Comment: When you boot the VM you can't add a password because you need to login first.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood but didn’t you say there isn’t a password?

Comment: It doesn't have a standard password but it doesn't start a root shell either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me to configure the SSH key and a few other things on the VM. In my case I am using VMWare and creating a machine from an OVA file.

Basically you have to create 3 config files and then put them in an iso file which you then mount as a CD when you boot the VM and then cloud-init configures your machine.

Run these commands to create the three config files:

```
cat <<EOF > user-data
#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: mylinuxuser
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa .... REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR SSH KEY FROM ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
EOF
 
cat <<EOF > meta-data
# change the instance-id every time you make changes to cloud-init files or it may not apply the changes
instance-id: iid-local01
local-hostname: devlin2
EOF
 
cat <<EOF > network-config
version: 1
config:
  - type: physical
    # this is the name of an existing interface it will find and then configure with these settings - in ubuntu 20 this is ens192
    name: ens192
    subnets:
      - type: static
        address: 10.2.2.23/24
        gateway: 10.2.2.1
        dns_nameservers:
          - 10.2.2.7
          - 10.2.2.9
        dns_search:
          - dv-wh
EOF

# install the genisoimage tool
sudo apt install genisoimage

# create an iso containing the above 3 files
genisoimage -output nocloud1.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data network-config
```

Next go to virtualbox or vmware and mount this ISO as a CD and reboot the machine.